# lightning:recordEditForm support for guest users

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

Is the `lightning:recordEditForm` component considered part of the lightning data service? I'm aware that lightning data service is only available in lightning experience. I don't see anything in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm?search_text=lightning:component) saying otherwise.

When I try to load the `lightning:recordEditForm` component in a visualforce page, available to guest users, I get the following error

[image]

This is what my lightning app looks like that is created on a visualforce page

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outAppUnstyled" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:pageContainer"/>
</aura:application>
```

Comment: Which object are you inserting/updating data ?I was wondering if guest users have access to it ?

Comment: when I remove Shipping_Country__c and Shipping_State__c from the form, both picklists, the page loads. Those fields, the guest user has read/edit access.

Comment: I can confirm the bug. This happens with Picklist in my cases (didn't try lookup). FLS, Objects Rights, etc. is all ok. Trying to give all possible permissions is not helping either.